# NVL replacement in Presto SQL - ISNULL or COALESCE not serving purpose

Tags: sql, presto

I have an optional parameter in my presto SQL query I tried many articles but none has worked for me.

I need something like this:

```
on c.portfolio_code = x.portfolio_code

/* this is a conditional parameter, this can be a null */

and c.portfolio_code = coalesce( '{p_portfolio_code}', x.portfolio_code)
```

when I try `ISNULL( '{p_portfolio_code}', x.portfolio_code)`  its saying unrecognized function error

```
and (c.portfolio_code = ‘{p_portfolio_code}’ or ‘{p_portfolio_code}’ is null)

and (c.portfolio_code = ‘{p_portfolio_code}’ or ‘{p_portfolio_code}’ = ‘’)
```

Please help I tried many approaches but of no use.

Comment: Can you please add the whole query. And possibly some sample data and desired output?

Comment: Also how do you run the query?

Comment: Guys great thanks I found the answer by hit and trial, I checked for null as a string value and it worked

Answer (score 0):

> and case '{p_portfolio_code}' when 'null' then 1=1 else Portfolio_Code = '{p_portfolio_code}' end

I tried the above and it resolved my issue, when no Parameter is passed, I checked it with 'null' and it worked.

Thanks **Guru Stron** for your help